# Decode MIME Message and display on ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, mime

I have multipart mail message MIME stored in SQL database. I want to retrieve and display it on the ASP page. I tried decoding it manually but it was not so accurate. There are many types of encoding base64, Iso, printedQuotable etc.

Is there easy way of decoding MIME messages in C#?

Answer (score 0):

Try out this
http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/163362/How-To-decode-mime-format-in-asp-net

Let me know if you want more..